# Algorithm Running Time for O(n.m^2)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I would like to know, because I couldn't find any information online, how is an algorithm like `O(n * m^2)` or `O(n * k)` or `O(n + k)` supposed to be analysed?

Does only the `n` count?

The other terms are superfluous?

So `O(n * m^2)` is actually `O(n)`?

Comment: if n  and m depend on input then none of them are superflous

Comment: yes, the input parameters are m>=1 and n>=1. So the running time could be described as polynomial? And we take into account only the highest order term?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "analysed"? The complexity of some algorithms depend on more than one variable. For example, the complexity of multiplying a `m` by `n` matrix by a `n` by `m` matrix is `O(n*m^2)`--you need to perform `n` multiplications per element in the resulting matrix and there are `m^2` elements.

Comment: Pardon me for my phrasing. What I meant was how I am supposed to think about the running time. For example, is this algorithm polynomial? And if n is constant, is the algorithm quadratic?

Comment: I would consider the `O(n*m^2)` case polynomial. You might say it is "quandratic in `m`" and "linear in `n`". As you said, if `n` is constant, then the algorithm is quadratic in `m`. If we hold `m` constant, then it becomes linear in `n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, here the k and m terms are not superfluous,they do have a valid existence and essential for computing time complexity. They are wrapped together to provide a concrete-complexity to the code.

It may seem like the terms n and k are independent to each other in the code,but,they both combinedly determines the complexity of the algorithm.

Say, if you've to iterate a loop of size n-elements, and, in between, you have another loop of k-iterations, then the overall complexity turns O(nk).

Complexity of order **O(nk)**, you can't dump/discard k here.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
for(j=0;j<k;j++)
// do something
```

Complexity of order **O(n+k)**, you can't dump/discard k here.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
// do something
for(j=0;j<k;j++)
// do something
```

Complexity of order **O(nm^2)**, you can't dump/discard m here.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
for(j=0;j<m;j++)
for(k=0;k<m;k++)
// do something
```

> Answer to the last question---So O(n.m^2) is actually O(n)?

No,O(nm^2) complexity can't be reduced further to O(n) as that would mean `m` doesn't have any significance,which is not the case actually.

Comment: Just to make sure, can you please tell me: if n is constant, is the algorithm quadratic? And if m is constant is the algorithm linear?

Comment: If n is constant, then you can remove n terms from all of them orderly as n will be calculated in O(1);;; hence the complexity as hinted in my answer will be O(k),O)k), and O(m^2).

Answer (score 1):

FORMALLY:  O(f(n)) is the SET of ALL functions T(n) that satisfy:

There exist positive constants c and N such that, for all n >= N,

```
                          T(n) <= c f(n)
```

Here are some examples of when and why factors other than n matter.

[1]  1,000,000 n  is in  O(n). Proof:  set c = 1,000,000, N = 0.

Big-Oh notation doesn't care about (most) constant factors. We generally leave constants out; it's unnecessary to write O(2n), because O(2n) = O(n).  (The 2 is not wrong; just unnecessary.)

[2]  n  is in  O(n^3).  [That's n cubed]. Proof:  set c = 1, N = 1.
  Big-Oh notation can be misleading.  Just because an algorithm's running time is in O(n^3) doesn't mean it's slow; it might also be in O(n).  Big-Oh notation only gives us an UPPER BOUND on a function.

[3]  n^3 + n^2 + n  is in  O(n^3). Proof:  set c = 3, N = 1.
   Big-Oh notation is usually used only to indicate the dominating (largest
     and most displeasing) term in the function.  The other terms become
     insignificant when n is really big.

These aren't generalizable, and each case may be different. That's the answer to the questions: **"Does only the n count? The other terms are superfluous?"**

Answer (score -1):

Although there is already an accepted answer, I'd still like to provide the following inputs :

```
O(n * m^2) : Can be viewed as n*m*m and assuming that the bounds for n and m are similar then the complexity would be O(n^3).
```

Similarly -

```
O(n * k) : Would be O(n^2) (with the bounds for n and k being similar)
```

and -

```
O(n + k) : Would be O(n) (again, with the bounds for n and k being similar).
```

PS: It would be better not to assume the similarity between the variables and to first understand how the variables relate to each other (Eg: m=n/2; k=2n) before attempting to conclude.

Comment: `O(n * k) : Would be O(n^2) (with the bounds for n and k being similar)`----no,it won't be. Give, n and k and m are independent, you just ca't draw conclusions like this! OP hasn't provided any extra information in the question.

Comment: Correct, the OP has not provided the info. Hence it'd be wrong to assume 'no' as well. In any case I have included that in the post script.

Comment: Generalisation should be preferred over concretisation. Next, this answer doesn't add anything new than the other 2 answers. You just want to turn the table by providing values to k and m!